# Converting a string numbers list into a float numbers list

Tags: python

I`ve been trying to convert a string numbers list into float and get the max of this list but I keep getting this error:

`ValueError: could not convert string to float: '.'`

My attempt was to get a list like `ls = ['1','2','3','0.5']` and convert using this function

```
def convert_to_int(ls: list):
    values = [float(a) for a in ls]
    return (len(values), values)

print(max(ls, key=convert_to_int))
```

Why I'm having this error? Can someone help me?

Comment: `key` should be a function which applies to individual elements, not to lists of elements. Also -- why are you calling a function designed to covert to floats `convert_to_int`?

Comment: Did you mean `max(convert_to_int(ls)[1])`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think, what you're looking for is:

```
max(ls, key=float)
```

output: `'3'`

This will get the max value of your string list, using a temporary `float` conversion within `max`

Answer (score 1):

There is a more straight way to do this.

```
ls = ['1','2','3','0.5']
res = max(map(float, ls))
print(res)

Output:
3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Using convert_to_int and ls from the question:

```py
def convert_to_int(ls: list):
    values = [float(a) for a in ls]
    return (len(values), values)

ls = ['1','2','3','0.5']

print(max(*convert_to_int(ls)[1]))
```

3.0

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/31247857)

Comment: @SumitSChawla how does that not answer the question? Please don't confuse *"bad"* answers to *"not an"* answer. If you think this answer is bad - down vote. But we don't delete answers that answer the question

Comment: @SumitSChawla I also can't understand your objection.

Comment: @MichaelGrazebrook: If you feel the answer is correct. Please add more details to it with sample input and output so that it is clear.

Comment: @SumitSChawla It seems pedantic to repeat the question but there you are!